# String isn't set to the right value

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an app in Android Studio. I'm stuck because of the following problem.
I want to change the room String in the first line to the value of the room String in void onDataChange. I've tried so many things but it keeps having the value null.

```
 private String room;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ref = new Firebase("https://firebase.com/users/" + getPhoneId().toString() + "/" + receivingUser.toString());
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                room = (String) snapshot.child("room").getValue().toString();
                setRoom(room);
            }
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("chat/" + room);
```

Comment: that is your api problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the following block of code is a call-back which will not execute until relevant event is triggered.

```
   ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            room = (String) snapshot.child("room").getValue().toString();
            setRoom(room);
        }
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
```

The above code only creates an object of a sub-class of `ValueEventListener`. Creating an object of class will not automatically call all it's methods. Therefore, `onDataChange` method is not called in the above code. Subsequently, the following block of code will always see `room` to be `null` :

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("chat/" + room);
```

Comment: Okay, I see. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Funk It's practically impossible for me to tell you how to fix your code from the short snippet of your actual code that you have posted. If I have to take a blind guess, I would move the statement `mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("chat/" + room);` inside the `onDataChange` method. When you run the app, you should trigger the `DataChange` event through the user interface (e.g click a button) so that the `onDataChange` method is called.

Answer (score -2):

You should do something like that:

```
room = snapshot.child("room").getValue().toString();
```

instead of:

```
room = (String) snapshot.child("room").getValue().toString();
```

You should not cast something to a String if you convert it to a String with "toString()".

Comment: What is the difference between the 2? I mean with and without casting?

Comment: You should not cast an Object to String like that if it is not actually a String object. So if you must convert it to a String with toString(), casting to String with (String) won't work. Actually you should never use both.

Comment: @YBrin This is not relevant to the current question and also not the reason why the `room` is always `null`.